# Sapper/svelte: How to import util js that uses session

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

I want to create a utility that handles some stuff with session, something like:

```
SessionUtil.js
import { stores } from '@sapper/app';
const { session } = stores();
export class SessionUtil {
  constructor(){}
  isAuthenticated() {
    return $session.token != null;
  }
  getAccess(){
    if ($session.token) {
      return $session.token.access;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

And then use it in Svelte components like so:

```
    import SessionUtil from '../../auth/SessionUtil.js';
    let sessionUtil = new SessionUtil();
//...
<Textfield disabled={sessionUtil.getAccess() > .5}>
```

When I do this, I get:

```
Error: Function called outside component initialization
```

Comment: You can't use auto subscriptions like $session is a js file. But you can use session.subscribe(...) . More here: Auto-subscription only works with store variables that are declared (or imported) at the top-level scope of a component. https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions